# How to delete a current row by clicking row' delete button in html table?

Tags: jquery, html

I am new jquery and in my project The rows will gets updated dynamically.

Now my question is how to delete a row when we click that rows delete button. Kindly some one help me to do this.

```
<table
        class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed tableSiteUser">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>SiteName</th>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Channel</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="site-table-body">
            <tr>
                <td class="countsiteuser">1</td>
                <td><select class="form-control"><option>www.google.com</option>
                        <option>www.yahoo.com</option>
                        <option>www.flipkart.com</option>
                        <option>www.gamil.com</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="user" id="checkboxbutton"><input
                    type="text" class="and" placeholder="Default"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter the Channel"></td>
                <td><span
                    class="form-control glyphicon glyphicon-trash siteUserrow-remover1"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="beer" contenteditable="false">2</td>
                <td><select class="form-control"><option>www.google.com</option>
                        <option>www.yahoo.com</option>
                        <option>www.flipkart.com</option>
                        <option>www.gamil.com</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="user" id="checkboxbutton"><input
                    type="text" class="and" disabled="" placeholder="Default"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter the Channel"></td>
                <td><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash form-control row-remover"2=""></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="beer" contenteditable="false">3</td>
                <td><select class="form-control"><option>www.google.com</option>
                        <option>www.yahoo.com</option>
                        <option>www.flipkart.com</option>
                        <option>www.gamil.com</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="user" id="checkboxbutton"><input
                    type="text" class="and" disabled="" placeholder="Default"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter the Channel"></td>
                <td><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash form-control row-remover"3=""></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Please provide me some jsfiddle examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the containing `<tr>` by using jQuery's `.closest()` function.  This walks up the DOM hierarchy until it finds an element that matches the provided selector.

```
$('span.glyphicon-trash').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Checkout this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/0vhg0c7m/

See the docs for `.closest()`: [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: @Brijesh Bhatt, the OP never said rows are ADDED dynamically, only that they are UPDATED dynamically. Presumably these updates wouldn't affect the delete column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4pLd4aes/)

```
$('.row-remover').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt, dont worry we can use event delegation for the same.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt, your particular comment was not considered in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the class `glyphicon-trash` is the delete row. You can use the following query code

```
$(function() {
    $('.glyphicon-trash').on('click', function() {
       // remove the current TR
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows are adding dynamically, use **[EVENT DELEGATION](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'table.tableSiteUser tr td:last', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cd1538Lq/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

use closest method to find the tr and use remove method  to remove the tr

```
    $(function () {
        $("body").on('click', '.row-remover', function() {
              $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
```

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alenjoy333/4pLd4aes/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use same class name for all action span, your first span use class 'siteUserrow-remover1' and other span use row-remover. Use same class name for all span that used for delete action

Also include latest jquery as older jquery did not support 'on' function

Here is working example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.row-remover').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
    })
});
</script>
<style>
.row-remover{ border:1px solid #ddd;}
</style>
<table
        class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed tableSiteUser">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>SiteName</th>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Channel</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="site-table-body">
            <tr>
                <td class="countsiteuser">1</td>
                <td><select class="form-control"><option>www.google.com</option>
                        <option>www.yahoo.com</option>
                        <option>www.flipkart.com</option>
                        <option>www.gamil.com</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="user" id="checkboxbutton"><input
                    type="text" class="and" placeholder="Default"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter the Channel"></td>
                <td><span class="form-control glyphicon glyphicon-trash siteUser row-remover">delete</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="beer" contenteditable="false">2</td>
                <td><select class="form-control"><option>www.google.com</option>
                        <option>www.yahoo.com</option>
                        <option>www.flipkart.com</option>
                        <option>www.gamil.com</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="user" id="checkboxbutton"><input
                    type="text" class="and" disabled="" placeholder="Default"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter the Channel"></td>
                <td><span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash form-control row-remover">delete</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="beer" contenteditable="false">3</td>
                <td><select class="form-control"><option>www.google.com</option>
                        <option>www.yahoo.com</option>
                        <option>www.flipkart.com</option>
                        <option>www.gamil.com</option></select></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="user" id="checkboxbutton"><input
                    type="text" class="and" disabled="" placeholder="Default"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter the Channel"></td>
                <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash form-control row-remover">delete</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```